# Is it possible to repeat function exclude one method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myfunction = function(){

         $('.menu').delay(3000).slideDown("fast").attr('style', 'color:#fff')

        return false;
});
```

Can i repeat myfunction exclude `delay(3000)`?

Means something like `$('#submit').click(myfunction);` but myfunction should exclude `.delay(3000)`

Comment: You can't change the code of a function once it has been created. You'll have to pass an extra parameter or something and include the delay conditionally.

Comment: Or pass a parameter indicating how long the delay should be, and pass 0 if you want no delay.  Makes for slightly more compact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your function up with a variable for time:

```
var myfunction = function(delayTime) {
    $('.menu').delay(delayTime).slideDown("fast").attr('style', 'color:#fff')
    return false;
});
```

Then call it with the time value as an argument:

```
myfunction(3000);
```

or

```
myfunction(0);
```

Comment: You can also use a default value to avoid having to pass in 0.

Comment: Can a function used as a click handler take a parameter?

Comment: @eric $('#submit').click(function(){myfunction(3000)})

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, I like to create a curried function (that is, a function that returns a function).

```
function myFunction(doDelay){
  return function(){
    $('.menu').delay(doDelay ? 3000 : 0).slideDown('fast') //...
    return false
  }
}
```

Then you could set up your click listener like

```
$('#submit').click(myFunction(false))
```

And call it with the delay like `myFunction(true)()`, or create different delayed instances like `var myFunctionDelayed = myFunction(true)` or `var myFunctionNoDelay = myFunction(false)`

Comment: This one great too, but personally i more like isherwood one